# Command to find a word inside given directory

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, cmd.exe

I am using **windows 10**. I have directory structure like given below :

```
Test --> A --> A.txt
     --> B --> B.doc
     --> C --> C1 --> C1.java
     --> D --> D1 --> D2 --> D3.java
```

I want to **find occurence** of word "**ABCD**" in my root directory **Test**.

When I was using ubuntu, I was used to find this by command `grep -r "ABCD"`.

Is there any way to find these via command in cmd or any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command called `findstr` in Windows that functions similar to grep.  The `/S` command will search subdirectories, similar to the `-r` from grep.

If it does not need to be in a command prompt, Windows Search will look into files that it knows how to read (documents and text files, mostly) by default and will return results matching either the file name or file contents.  It can be limited to only within the files if you want.  However, I have not found this to be very fast or accurate.

If the command prompt method is not necessary, then my best suggestion is to use the program [grepWin](http://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html).  It is fast, highly configurable, supports regular expressions, and best of all, it is free.  It can even be used to find and replace strings within supported files.